# change styles from angular.json as dynamic

Tags: angular

Now , I have defined the default css files in angular.json file like this

```
    "styles": [
      "src/assets/demo5/base/style-A.css",
      "src/assets/vendors/base/vendors-A.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
```

I want when user click on a function the default CSS files should be replaced

```
"styles": [
  "src/assets/demo5/base/style-B.css",
  "src/assets/vendors/base/vendors-B.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Comment: As far as I know angular, you can not change content of angular.json file directly from any component.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers okay but if I put the css files into index.html ! it will be doable ?

Comment: The styles you add to the `angular.json` are actually only used during bundling by the webpack. So, it is already part of the `dist` generated when you build the application. I am assuming that you want to theme the application from the question, by dynamically modifying the style.


----------

Comment: @DhananjaiPai yes, but how can I do that ?

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo: I am exactly looking for this (i.e. changing css files runtime). Have you found any workaround?

Comment: I've been looking into switching out the styles.scss file in the app based on the build flag you pass to it, similar to how we switch out the environment files based on build in the angular.json. Haven't succeeded yet though.